# How to add parameter end of url with jQuery and checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, checkbox

I want to create checkbox filter for search. 
For example, I searching about `sunglass`. At result page, sunglasses are from all of brands, and search URL is:
http://www.my-site.com/?s=sunglass 
when I check the `Rayban`, I want to add some parameters like `&brand=rayban` at end of this url. Like:
http://www.my-site.com/?s=sunglass&brand=rayban 
And when unchecking it, URL back to original state `?s=sunglass`.

HTML code is:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="rayban"/>
```

jQuery code is:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
    var data = [],
        loc = $('<a>', {href:window.location})[0];
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i){
    if(this.checked){
        data.push(this.name+'='+this.value);

    }
    });
    data = data.join('&');

    if(history.pushState){
        history.pushState(null, null, loc.pathname+'?'+data);
location.reload();
    }
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with something like this.Hope this will help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
  
  $(function(){
 

  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function(e){
       
      var loc = location.href;
      loc = loc.split("&")[0]; // to get the URL till /?s=sunglass
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i){
      if(this.checked){
         loc += "&" + $(this).attr("name") + "=" + $(this).attr("value");
         }
      });
      location.href = loc;
  });
 
});
  
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
<input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="rayban"/> 
 <input type="checkbox" name="brand" value="armani"/> 
  </body>

</html>
```